# How to find whether an object is of type formcontroller in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular, forms

I have a nested form. I want to validate it recursively. While validating, I need to check whether the object is of type Formcontroller or not. When trying instance of or type of, I am getting it as an object, not the form controller. Kindly help to find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if an object is of a certain type, I believe you could ask something like this:

```js
  person = {
     id: 1,
     name: 'John',
     age: 46,
     active: true
  };

  house = {
     color: 'blue with white patterns',
     years: 20,
     isInGoodCondition: true
  };

  const myArray = [person, house];

  myArray.forEach((element) => {
     if (element?.name) console.log('It is a person object');
     if (element?.isInGoodCondition) console.log('It is a house object');
  });
```

The `object?.property` asks safely if that `property` exists inside your object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andres. But my question is related to Form Controller. I just want to find whether the object is of type Form controller in angular js

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is Form Controller or any object, javascript will always returns `object` as a data type.  If you want to determine if an object is of type `FormController`, then you can ask for a certain property that you know for sure FormController has. I believe this is not related to angularJS.

Comment: Thanks Andres. Seems like I have to use property as you told